# What is the big-theta of the following code? [I*I <= n]

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, code-complexity

```
for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
   for (i = 1; i*i <= n; i++)
       // some O(1) operations`
```

I am asked to find the big-theta of this code. I figured by `i*i < n`. I can rewrite it as `I < n/I`. And so tracing it I got the following:

```
I                # of interations
1               n
2               n/2
3               n/3
.                .
.                .
.                .
n/L              1
```

Though I am not sure how to go from here. Should I calculate the summation of n/i from i=0 to n? In that case how do I calculate the sum when a variable (n) is present?

I know that if I find L I find the number of iterations needed. And as it terminates after L = N/L I can't calculate L in terms of N.

I am very confused with this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop has N iterations. The inner loop has squareroot(N) iterations.  Multiply those two to find the answer.